# Laravel nova action - get current model instance on fields()

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

Laravel 5.8
Nova 2.0

In nova action

```
public function fields()
{
    return [];
}
```

Is there any way to access currently selected rows here?

Answer (score 4):

You can get current model instance from NovaRequest. And you may create NovaRequest from \Illuminate\Http\Request that is passed to the method:

```php
use Laravel\Nova\Http\Requests\NovaRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

/**
 * Get the fields displayed by the resource.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return array
 */
public function fields(Request $request)
{
   // Model instance or null
   $model = NovaRequest::createFrom($request)
      ->findModelQuery()
      ->first();

   return [
     // Your fields here
   ];
}
```

Comment: seems to make sense, will be helpful, if you will add some reference to this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if anyone solved this but I got the same issue and found an [article](https://meki.medium.com/context-aware-table-row-actions-for-laravel-nova-51087f3176a8).

According to this article, you can create a public method `setResource` in action class and when registering action in nova resource, set the current resource of each row: `$action->setResource($this->resource)`. Then, in `fields` method, you can add your logic with resource by using `$this ->resource`.

A note for this method is `$this->resource` can be `null` or an `null` model (a model class but no attribute). Thus, you must check the resource property if it is `null` before adding any logic.

Answer (score 1):

No, for two reasons:

1) `fields` is called when the resource loads, not when the action dialog is displayed

2) The concept of "currently selected" really only exists on the client (browser) side

You can only access the selected rows in the `handle` PHP method (i.e., after submit, you have `$models`).

Comment: When resource loads, the resource is of a model, correct, I wanted that in fields. If the model is not available at that moment, how we can display the resource?

Comment: Nova actions are not tied to a particular model instance (or a group of models), but to the resource definition. Does that make sense?

Comment: Is there any way to get respective model from a particular resource?

Comment: Only within the "handle" method

Comment: In my opinion this is a "design flaw" in Nova, because yes we understand the reasons why it's so, but Actions are one of the most powerful features and the lack of this ability stifles possibilities.

Comment: I totally agree @EugenevanderMerwe it would be so powerful if we could base the fields on the amount of hasmany records selected for instance, and add model data in the actions view. we are looking in customizing to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes when I'm on the details view and want to perform an action on that record, but also want the current records data in the fields (maybe for help text), I grab it from the URL.

```
//Get the URL
    $explodeUrl = explode('/', strrev($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']), 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

I run the action only on the detail page then get the single model data like so:

```
$model = DB::table('something')->where('id', request()->resourceId)->first();
```

Comment: If it will work, you can just do `Model::find(request()->resourceId)` . do not have Nova now, so can not confirm though.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a `handleRequest` function and retrieve the model that way. For instance

```
public function handleRequest(ActionRequest $request)
    {
        $this->model = $request->targetModel(); //I am setting a custom variable here.
        parent::handleRequest($request);
    }
```

You can then use the `$this->model()` in your `handle()` method.

Very useful for standalone actions.